# MVC HTML.DropDownList set width

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I set the the LOV of dropdownlist in Controller by putting them into a ViewData and displaying them at View using the following code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("dropDown_"+item.ConfigCode);
```

The dropdownlist does displayed as I wanted and I'm now stuck at changing the width of it. Based on what I've found on the net, the following code should be working, however, it is not showing any value for the drop down list. May I know what should I do with it?

```
@Html.DropDownList("dropDown_"+item.ConfigCode, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),new {      @style = "width: 50px;" })
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need the `@` before style and also you need to pass in the ViewData into the DropDownList source:

```
@Html.DropDownList("dropDown_"+item.ConfigCode, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["dropDown_"+item.ConfigCode] ,new { style = "width: 50px;" })
```

You only need to escape keywords with the `@` symbol if they are C# keywords, for example `class`

Comment: Thanks for that but it has nothing to do with my question at all. The size does changed however it does not showing any data. I think it has something to do with Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(). But what should I replace with it

Comment: Make sure your `ViewData` is populated and `ViewData["dropdown_" + item.ConfigCode]` is not null. Works for me.

Comment: Don't set it to null in your Controller/Model. Make sure it is some form of IEnumerable